# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a un servidor público con XAMPP?

Tags: php, sql, apache, xampp, dominio

Tengo un sitio web hecho con SQL y PHP, lo vinculé a una base de datos de XAMPP y funciona en entorno local, pero al subir el sitio web en un entorno público, dicha base de datos deja de responder, no envía  datos al sitio, subí el sitio web con apache.

Comment: Buenas, Mario, ¿a qué te refieres con una base de datos de xampp? Supongo que la instalación de xampp en local te instala también un servidor de base de datos en local y que es esa base de datos a la que te refieres. Efectivamente desde un entorno público no puedes acceder a tu local. Tienes que consultar a tu proveedor de alojamiento para que te proporcione ese servicio de base de datos donde sea que estés subiendo tu web y replicar ahí tu base de datos y configurar tu sitio web para que acceda a esa base de datos.